# How to fix problem with MSX Composite Video?

Tags: msx, troubleshooting

I have a Toshiba HX-10 64KB MSX1 computer (PAL video output). I recently used a new cassette cable which caused a problem with the video; I am using the AV composite audio and video; because the video looks distorted similar to when it would just be tuned out if it was plugged into an analog CRT TV and the sound here sounds distorted too; however when I sometimes wiggle the cassette lead (though not always) or turn the computer upside down then the MSX works as normal (i.e. video and sounds look perfect). What may be the problem with it and how to fix it?

Comment: Maybe a broken solder joint. A good first step is to closely inspect the PCB for cracked solder, broken traces, corrosion, burnt components, and bulging capacitors.

Comment: @snips-n-snails Do you know if this computer can be open without taking precautions for static electricity damaging any chips?